# How to get multiple outputs from scipy.optimize.root?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, root, multipleoutputs

I have nonlinear problem with multiple outputs of the following type:

```
[F,out1,out2,out3] = f(x,a,b,c)
```

I am trying to solve it in Python by method Levenberg-Marquardt in the way:

```
xSol = scipy.optimize.root(lambda x: f(x,a,b,c), x0, method='lm')
```

If I specify no outputs, i.e. `F = f(x,a,b,c)`, the method converges to correct solution x, but I cannot get my other solution values, i.e. out1, out2, out3.

According to [DOC](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root), the root function does not provide option for multiple outputs, i.e. `full_output=True` like e.g. fsolve or bisec (which does not provide a good solution to my problem).

Here goes simplified example of the problem:

```
    def root2d(x): 
        F = [np.exp(-np.exp(-(x[0] + x[1]))) - x[1] * (1 + x[0] ** 2)] 
        F.append(x[0] * np.cos(x[1]) + x[1] * np.sin(x[0]) - 0.5) 

        out = x[0]+x[1] # other results, which I would like to get too 
        return (F,out) # it yields error, but it works/converges with only "return F" 

    # --- run the test code with the root solver 
    x0 = [0,0] 
    x = root(root2d, x0) # how could I get also value of "out"? 
    print(x)
```

Comment: it was my understanding that the output `x` is an array giving all the roots

Comment: correct, x contains roots/solution, whereas I need to get values of some other parameters

Comment: what other outputs are you after? The roots are the solution.

Comment: function f(x,a,b,c) has about 1000+ lines of code, x provides solution to the math problem whereas does not contain rest of the results at final x, which I would like to get in terms of out1,out2,...

Comment: what other results? you're not being clear enough, what are `out1, out2, out3`? what other solution other than the math solution? its impossible to guess at what you mean without at least a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to achieve. Are you after an evalution of your function at a given point?

Comment: update your question with the example. Its impossible to read properly as a comment